# How to change font on css?

Tags: java, css, fonts, javafx, jfxtras

I'm trying to manipulate the font in Agenda from jfxtras (javafx).

I have a css file linked to it.

I figured out how to make it black and bold as well.

```
.AgendaText {
    -fx-text-fill: BLACK;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

But I don't know how to change the font to say, Arial.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser will try to take first font, second font and if it wont be able to find it it will serve a sans serif system font

```
.AgendaText {
        font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif
    }
```

Comment: Let me know if you find any irregularities with CSS. It is quite a complex control and I have limited tests on rendering with different CSS styling.